# MathJax Color fights Hidden Text and Wins!

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, mathjax, spoilers

It appears that using MathJax color in a hidden text block "pokes through" the hidden environment.  I don't believe this is desired behavior, so I'm reporting as a bug.

> very hidden.  $\color{red}{\text{Not so hidden...}}$ Hidden again.

Comment: Disclaimer: I know nothing about this! While certainly a surprise, this may be A) not so easy to fix, if the working of the spoiler field relies on turning black text to grey and back, B) a feature as opposed to a bug or, if you prefer, by-design :-)

Comment: I thought it wouldn't be easy to fix, but I still felt that reporting the behavior would be better than leaving it undocumented.

Comment: I think this is a legitimate bug, though likely in the "won't fix" territory. The spoilers indeed work by making the color of text identical to background, and MathJax, running later on the page, overrules that.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the behavior does *not* exist on the Android app.

Comment: This might just be me being naïf with my limited skills, but wouldn't simply applying something like [hidden](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp) instead of changing the color solve this? I imagine there are other technical problems with that though.

Comment: This behavio**u**r also does not exist on mobile site (click "mobile" in the footer). Both the mobile site and the app implement spoilers differently, by replacing the text with "[Click to show] spoiler", and then inserting the text if clicked.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi [Shog says](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110570/259867) it's because of reasons, some of the reasons being copy-paste and ability to display the text by selecting it.

Comment: @Behaviour I don't really understand the argument, since you can click on the spoiler block to make it visible. How about [opacity](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_opacity.asp) otherwise?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I never knew about click-to-keep-visible. Thanks! The post I linked is from 2011, so it's quite possible that by now whatever reasons made them use the color attribute for spoilers no longer apply.

Comment: [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) fixes this, as a side effect of [this general spoiler CSS fix.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217779/the-css-for-spoilers-is-a-mess-lets-fix-it) (It seems to break the click-to-keep-visible functionality, though. I'll fix that ASAP; thanks for pointing it out!)

Comment: ...and the click functionality is fixed too, as of SOUP v1.26.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why you're using colored text in spoiler blocks, but the obvious solution here is to just **not use colored text in spoiler blocks.**

Spoilers are fairly reader-hostile by-design, so if something about them strikes you as odd perhaps you could just skip using them entirely.

Comment: ...or just think about the color-blinded readers, and don't use colored text at all.

Comment: That's even better.

Comment: @AsafKaragila It's possible to use colored text in ways that even color-blind readers can distinguish. Colored text is frequently useful.

Comment: @Arkamis: I know. I've opened a meta thread about this issue some long time ago, you can probably find it and see for yourself. (I'm not saying that colors should never be used, but more often than not, their use can be replaced by something monochromatic.)

Comment: This is as much of an answer as a doctor saying "oh, it hurts when you jump on one foot? Don't do that--no one needs to jump on one foot anyway." :P However, as a programmer, I understand that this issue is *so* minor that it's most likely not worth fixing.

Comment: Yes, it is exactly like that, @anorton. "Doctor, holding my hand in front of my face hurts when I suddenly draw my hand inwards!" What do you want me to say, "oh, let's engineer a hole in your face?" Obviously, if you have a good reason for putting colored text in spoilers (and for using spoilers *at all* on a math site) then you should elaborate on that in your bug report - as it is, I consider this a feature implemented for the benefit of folks on sites for speculative fiction, and sort of a misfeature everywhere else.

Comment: @Shog9 well played, well played.  :)

Comment: @Shog: There are excellent reasons for using spoiler tags on a math site, actually. You give a hint, or a partial solution, and add a spoiler with the final answer, or a more elaborate hint. But I do like that attitude about engineering a hole in someone's face just so they can push their hand through!